# How to run BackgroundTask between specific times?

Tags: react-native

*I want to get locations between specific times. (forexample: 14:00 - 15:00) how do I do this ?*

*I use background-task :* [github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)

*But it runs every in 7m30s. could I decrease this time ?*

**here is my BackgroundTask code:**

```
    BackgroundTask.define(() => {

      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
        var lng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

          console.log("lat :",lat);
          console.log("lng :",lng);
    });

      BackgroundTask.finish()
    })

export default class App extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
  BackgroundTask.schedule();
}

}
```

*Any Idea ?*